# Unable to migrate to spring 3.2.3. possible Issue with messagingGateway

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-pubsub

While migrating from spring version 2.7.14 to 3.2.3, I'm getting following issue:

```
- UnsatisfiedDependency: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'puSubHandler';
- UnsatisfiedDependency: Error creating bean with name 'puSubHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messagingGateway';
- BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubsubOutboundGateway' defined in URL [jar:nested:<path/service/pubsubOutboundGateway.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
- BeanCrationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskSchedulingConfigurations$TaskSchedulerConfiguration.class]: Signature parse error : Exccepted a class type
- GenericSignatureFormatError : Signature parse error : Exccepted a class type
```

I am using `@messagingGateway` to send payload to my pubsub.

This is the class handling pubsub messages:

```
@Component
public class pubSubHandler{

@Autowired
private pubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway;

messagingGateway.sendToPubsub(payload);
}
```

This is the interface for `messagingGateway`:

```
@Service
@MessaginGateway(defaultRequestChannel="pubsubOutboundChannel")
public interface pubsubOutboundGateway{
void sendToPubsub(byte[] payload);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full stack trace.